# Blender rendering problem

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have downloaded a blender template and after editing it a bit, I set the proper settings and click 'render'. But instead of taking a few hours and rendering, in a few seconds it stops. When I find its video file and try playing it, it doesn't play. Please help me find a solution. I have followed all steps in all the rendering tutorials but still unsuccessful. I have tried searching for solutions but could not find any. The animation is 135 frames long and I have tried to render it frame by frame but have failed.

Comment: You are going to have to add more details in order for us to help you solve your issue. Are you using cycles or BI? How long of an animation are you rendering? Are you using any composition nodes or VSE strips? What happens if you render just one frame to a png? etc.

Comment: Look at it this way: We know nothing about your file, the settings you used, where you got the so called "template", what tutorials you followed or what other solutions you've tried. Please add some more information so someone can help you out.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. You might want to take the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and review the guidelines in the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help) on the topics of asking and answering questions. It would be helpful if you would upload a copy of your file to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), or a similar site, and edit a link into your original question.  What rendering tutorials have you followed?

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, we are all shooting in the dark.  Here are some basic troubleshooting tips:

Are you rendering anything?

- Are the cameras lit next to your objects in the scene Outliner?
- Are any scenes or layers selected in the Scene Properties tab
- Is the Frame Range in the Render Settings acceptable to you?
- Is the Frame Rate realistic?

Output Considerations

- Is the Aspect ratio and Screen Dimensions realistic?
- Is your output folder a realistic location? Is it writable from Blender?
- Are you outputting a actual video file type (AVI/MPEG/etc)?
- Have you considered rendering all the frames as pictures as stitching them together with VirtualDub?  Does even rendering individual frames work?

Other

- Can your video player even run the rendered codec?